# Having trouble checking when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, checkbox, socket.io

I'm trying to implement a like button into my site for some different pages and I'm using socket io so it updates for every user when the like button is pressed. I have a simple function of `like()` that emits `liked` which then makes a counter go up and displays on page. That's not the issue though. I decided to make a checkbox so I can do something when the checkbox is unliked. I have a function for that too that works. I just can't do something when it is unchecked. This is what I'm using to see if the checkbox is checked:

```js
if(document.getElementById('like').checked) {
  like()
}
```

This does nothing when it is checked though. I even tried to just replace `like()` with `socket.emit('liked')` but that didn't work either. What is the proper way of check if the checkbox is checked or not? (Preferably without Jquery)

Html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   </head>
   <body>
         <p id="likes">Likes: </p>
         <input type="checkbox" id="like"></input>
         <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
         <script>
             var socket = io.connect();
             
      if(document.getElementById('like').checked) {
        like()
      } 

             function like(){
               socket.emit('liked');
             }

       function un_like(){
               socket.emit('unliked');
             }
             
             socket.on('buttonUpdate', function(data){
                 document.getElementById("likes").innerHTML = 'Likes:  ' + data;
             });
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you add some HTML code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `addEventListener` to checkbox

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[id=like]");

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    console.log("Checkbox is checked..");
  } else {
    console.log("Checkbox is not checked..");
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="like">Checkbox</input>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `onChange` to handle this. [Additional reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="like" onChange="clickHandler(this)"></input>
```

```
function clickHandler(checkbox) {
   if(checkbox.checked) {
        like()
   } 
}
```

Sample code:

```js
function clickHandler(checkbox) {
   if(checkbox.checked) {
       console.log('selected')
   } else {
      console.log('unselected')
   }
}
```

```html
select / unselect: <input type="checkbox" id="like" onChange="clickHandler(this)"></input>
```